# How to get a filtered collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, local-storage, backbone-views

Lets suppose I have a `big collection` and I want to use a subset of this big collection for different view.

I tried the following code but it does not work because the `filtered collection` actually is a new one and it does not refer to the `BigCollection instance`.

My question is:
how can I get a collection which is a subset of `BigCollection instance`?

Here is my code. Please see the comments for more info:

```
// bigCollection.js
var BigCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    storageName: 'myCollectionStorage',
    // some code
});

// firstView.js
var firstView = Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
    initialize: function(){
        var filtered = bigCollection.where({type: 'todo'});
        this.collection = new Backbone.Collection(filtered);
        // the issue is about the fact 
        // this.collection does not refer to bigCollection
        // but it is a new one so when I save the data 
        // it does not save on localStorage.myCollectionStorage
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `BigCollection` to make filtered collection, like this :

```
    // firstView.js
    var firstView = Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
        initialize: function(){
            var filtered = bigCollection.where({type: 'todo'});
            this.collection = new BigCollection(filtered);
            // now, it will save on localStorage.myCollectionStorage
        }
    });
```

Comment: +1 yes your idea works great. Just one problem when I create a new model from the firstView the view is not re-render. is it normal?

Comment: @lorraine-bernard : Yes, It is normal. You should render the view manually.

Answer (score 0):

You could just save your original models in a variable inside your collection so you can restore them after you de-apply the filter, like this:

```
// bigCollection.js
var BigCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    storageName: 'myCollectionStorage',
    // some code
});

// firstView.js
var firstView = Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
    initialize: function(){
        bigCollection.original_models = bigCollection.models;
        bigCollection.models = bigCollection.where({type: 'todo'});
    }
});
```

And then you can restore them when you toggle the filter:

```
bigCollection.models = bigCollection.original_models;
```